# How to draw a CGridView after document ready?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gridview, yii

How to draw a CGridView after document ready? I have Yii framework 1.14, jquery and jquery.ui successfully loaded!

Console.error! Because the grid is draw after document ready

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).dialog is not a function 
jQuery("#dialog").dialog();
```

My code:

```
[
   'class' => 'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn',
   'template' => '{edit}',
   'headerHtmlOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1', 'style' => 'text-align:center'],
   'buttons' => [
       'edit' => [
           'label' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>',
           'url' => "Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('ViewComments',['key'=>\$data->key])",
           'imageUrl' => null,
           'options' => [
               'style' => 'color: black',
               'rel' => 'tooltip',
               'data-toggle' => 'modal',
               'data-target' => "#myModal",
               'title' => 'Комментировать',
               'ajax' => [
                   'type' => 'post',
                   'url' => 'js:$(this).attr("href")',
                   'dataType' => 'html',
                   'success' => 'js:function(data){
                           jQuery("#dialog").dialog();
                   }'
               ],
           ],
       ],
   ]
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reloading js in your view

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
   Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');

Comment: Yes, it was necessary in view, and I was charged to layout!